# UnityのMecanim+Humanoid　を使っている時にScriptから姿勢制御をしたいときの方法について

Tags: unity3d

## Unity5を使っています。

UnityのHumanoidを使ってアニメーションしている
キャラクターの腰（Spine）や首(Neck)の向きをScriptから制御したいと思っています。

GenericやLegacyの時はFixedUpdateでJountを回せば反映されたのですが
Mecanim+Humanoid利用時にはコントロールできませんでした。

腕や足はAvatorIKGoalでコントロールできるのですが、
腰（Spine)と首（Neck）はIKからは指定できません。

何か方法が無いか知っている方いますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

FixesUpdate ではなくLateUpdateを使うべきでした。

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html
Physicsの処理の後に回せば　やりたい事は実現できました。